# Changing CommonsMultipartResolver's maxUploadSize during runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload, apache-commons-fileupload

I am using a [CommonsMultipartResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/commons/CommonsMultipartResolver.html) for file upload.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" >
    <!-- specify maximum file size in bytes -->
<property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean
```

I want to be able to change its property maxUploadSize at runtime (so that the size may be changed by the administrator). What is the best way to do this please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can autowire `CommonsMultipartResolver` in your controller and update the property there at runtime.

For example:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/setMaxUploadSize", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView setMaxUploadSize() {
        ...
        multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(5000);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. The change is permanent and persist in other controller either - ok for me.