# Changing file size limit (maxUploadSize) depending on the controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc, upload

I have a Spring MVC web with two different pages that have different forms to upload different files. One of them should have a limitation of 2MB, while the other should have a 50MB limitation.

Right now, I have this limitation in my app-config.xml:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes (2097152 B = 2 MB) -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2097152 "/>
</bean>
```

And I could resolve the maxUploadSize exception in my main controller like that:

```
@Override
public @ResponseBody
ModelAndView resolveException(HttpServletRequest arg0,
        HttpServletResponse arg1, Object arg2, Exception exception) {
    ModelAndView modelview = new ModelAndView();
        String errorMessage = "";
        if (exception instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) {
            errorMessage =  String.format("El tamaño del fichero debe ser menor de  %s", UnitConverter.convertBytesToStringRepresentation(((MaxUploadSizeExceededException) exception)
                    .getMaxUploadSize()));

        } else {
            errorMessage = "Unexpected error: " + exception.getMessage();
        }
        saveError(arg0, errorMessage);
        modelview = new ModelAndView();
        modelview.setViewName("redirect:" + getRedirectUrl());
    }
    return modelview;
}
```

But this, obviously, only controlls the 2MB limit. How could I make the limitation for the 20MB one?
I've tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11792952/1863783, which updates the limitation in runtime. However, this updates it for every session and every controller. So, if one user is uploading a file for the first form, another using uploading in the second form should have the limitation of the first one...

Any help? thanks

Comment: check this out [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061209/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-when-configuring-maxuploadsize-of-commonmult/29635044#29635044)

Comment: I've raised pull request for this feature -https://github.com/apache/commons-fileupload/pull/22

Answer (score 8):

It may seem like not the best solution at first sight, but it depends on your requirements.

You can set a global option with maximum upload size for all controllers and override it with lower value for specific controllers.

application.properties file (Spring Boot)

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=50MB
```

Upload controller with check

```
public void uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file) {
    final long limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024;    // 2 MB
    if (file.getSize() > limit) {
        throw new MaxUploadSizeExceededException(limit);
    }
    StorageService.uploadFile(file);
}
```

In case of a file bigger than 2MB you'll get this exception in log:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MaxUploadSizeExceededException: Maximum upload size of 2097152 bytes exceeded
```

Comment: Does this let the whole file uploaded before processing? Look like it waste bandwidth and subject you to ddos?

Comment: @user1560335 I understand your concern, but I didn't check my code in this answer for DDoS sustainability. You are welcome to do your own research or [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

This is how it is possible: Override the `DispatcherServlet` class. An example would probably looke like the following:

```
public class CustomDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {

    private Map<String, MultipartResolver> multipartResolvers;

    @Override
    protected void initStrategies(ApplicationContext context) {
            super.initStrategies(context);
            initMultipartResolvers(context);
    }

    private void initMultipartResolvers(ApplicationContext context) {
            try {
                    multipartResolvers = new HashMap<>(context.getBeansOfType(MultipartResolver.class));
            } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException ex) {
                    // Default is no multipart resolver.
                    this.multipartResolvers = Collections.emptyMap();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpServletRequest checkMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) throws MultipartException {
            if (this.multipartResolvers.isEmpty() && this.multipartResolvers.get(0).isMultipart(request)) {
                    if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
                            logger.debug("Request is already a MultipartHttpServletRequest - if not in a forward, "
                                    + "this typically results from an additional MultipartFilter in web.xml");
                    } else {
                            MultipartResolver resolver = getMultipartResolverBasedOnRequest(request);
                            return resolver.resolveMultipart(request);
                    }
            }
            // If not returned before: return original request.
            return request;
    }

    private MultipartResolver getMultipartResolverBasedOnRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
            // your logic to check the request-url and choose a multipart resolver accordingly.
            String resolverName = null;
            if (request.getRequestURI().contains("SomePath")) {
                    resolverName = "resolver1";
            } else {
                    resolverName = "resolver2";
            }
            return multipartResolvers.get(resolverName);
    }
}
```

Assuming that you have configured multiple MultipartResolvers in your application-context (presumably named 'resolver1' and 'resolver2' in the example code).

Of course, when you configure the `DispatcherServlet` in your `web.xml`, you use this class instead of the Spring `DispatcherServlet`.

**Another way:** A [MultipartFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/MultipartFilter.html#lookupMultipartResolver%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) could be used as well. Just override the [lookupMultipartResolver(HttpServletRequest request)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/MultipartFilter.html#lookupMultipartResolver%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) method and look up the required resolver yourself. However, there are some ifs and buts to that. Look up the documentation before using that.

Answer (score 0):

There is an elegant solution here [Spring Boot: ClassNotFoundException when configuring maxUploadSize of CommonMultipartResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061209/spring-boot-classnotfoundexception-when-configuring-maxuploadsize-of-commonmult)

you can modify your application **application.properties** file to change the max upload size as you want

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BaseDispatcherServlet extends DispatcherServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doService(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
        CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = (CommonsMultipartResolver) getMultipartResolver();
        if (requestURI.contains("uriWithLargeFileSize")) {
            multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(100 * 100L);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the main author, and maintainer of Commons Fileupload, I'd propose the following, with regard to your usecase:

- Have two instances of FileUploadBase, one with a max size of 2MB, and another with 20MB. Depending on the request details (for example, by looking on the URI), use one, or the other instance.
- If you aren't using FileUpload directly (but Spring, Struts, or whatever in front), then, most likely, a change in Fileupload wouldn't suffice for you, because the Frontend won't support a possible new feature, at least not initially. In that case, I suggest that you start pushing the frontend developers to support your requirement. They can easily do that by creating an instance of FileUploadBase per request. (It's a lightweight object, as long as you're not using file trackers, or similar advanced features, so no problem with that.)
- I am ready to review, and possibly accept patches by you, or others, that replace the current check for maxUploadSize with a Predicate, or something similar.

Jochen