# How can I override the Spring MultipartResolver bean property for one function?

Tags: java, spring

I have a multipartResolver been which looks like the following:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"    
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="16777216"/>
</bean>
```

This gives a limit of 16 mb for file uploads, which is generally the limit I'd like to be enforced. However, for a one off scenario, I'd like to increase the limit for the file upload.

One way I can think of doing this is to make the bean configurable and raise the limit on this function call but that seems very sloppy. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585866/changing-file-size-limit-maxuploadsize-depending-on-the-controller OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790761/changing-commonsmultipartresolvers-maxuploadsize-during-runtime/11792952#11792952

Comment: damn i'm a bad searcher... thanks!